# Variable scope and includes

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following problem: in index.php,  I have set the variable $activelang. I

```
$activelang = active_language (); 
echo $activelang; //works perfectly
```

Later in my index.php code, I include a new php file.

```
include ('myotherfile.php');
```

If I try to use $activelang in myotherfile.php, it does not work! I am not using it inside a function, and I tried using global $activelang and it doesnt work either

All of these is happening in a wordpress install, but the code I am talking about is plain php. I am using php 5.3

Why is this happening? As I undestand it, the include works as a copy paste in my main file, so I shouldnt be having any problems with variable scope, right?

Comment: post here your real code. don't you include this file as HTTP resource, do you?

Comment: The problem is the context of your execution. Don't know much about WP installs, but it does most likely include your first script in a local scope. Hence $activelang was never a global.

Answer (score 1):

include should be used to include **files**, not some network resources.

if you bother to run **the code you posted here** you'll be surprized, as it will print $activelang all right.

Comment: Sorry but I dont know what you are talking about. Network resources? I am including a php file that is used by other files as well. And what do you mean by running the code I posted here?

Comment: @0al0 go test your code with plain PHP you mentioned, and you will see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

When working with WordPress templates you should create functions in your functions.php file for handling includes and then call those functions in your templates.

So in functions.php you should have:

```
function myOtherFile() {

    include('myotherfile.php');

}
```

And in index.php call myOtherFile()

Now, if you still have trouble with scope try this:

```
function myOtherFile($activelang) {

    include('myotherfile.php);

}
```

And then in index.php do this:

```
$activelang = active_language();

myOtherFile($activelang);
```

If that doesn't work then I think your problem is being caused elsewhere. Because like Col. Shrapnel said, the code you posted here works.